css margin-left vs margin-right behavior
Assuming my body has background color of green,
when I do margin-left to my Div I can see the margin in a different color (green) and an overflow, but when I do margin-rigt the behavior is different, I see no margin nor overflow. Is there an explanation or reason fro it?


* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.myDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(112, 112, 0);
  /**margin-left: 50px;*/
  margin-right: 50px; 
}
<body>
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
</body>




From the specification:

If all of the above have a computed value other than 'auto', the values are said to be "over-constrained" and one of the used values will have to be different from its computed value. If the 'direction' property of the containing block has the value 'ltr', the specified value of 'margin-right' is ignored and the value is calculated so as to make the equality true. If the value of 'direction' is 'rtl', this happens to 'margin-left' instead.

Note the direction which is very important and the default one is left-to-right ltr

In this case, it's because you set the div's width to 100%. Try setting it to auto.



* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: greenyellow;
}

.myDiv {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(112, 112, 0);
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}
<body>
  <div class="myDiv"></div>
</body>




Thank you. It's not that I want it to be symmetrical like that. I just wanted to know if the margin-right and margin-left are really behaving differently. The upshot is to understand better how CSS works.

@Nadirspam I'm no expert, but by adding a border (I use 1px solid red) to the body element, you can see that the div extends past it. I assume that it tries to apply both margins, but CSS tries to keep the div at 100% of its parent, the body. The right margin should be there, but it can't be because the right end of the div is outside of the body element.
